# Could not start a website in android emulator with capybara, appium, ruby

Tags: android, ruby, capybara, driver, appium

I try to open a website in chrome and native android browser (emulated Android 5.0 and 6) to check several items.
every time i run the test, the choosen browser get started and in the url field stays 'data:,' btw the actual tab is also loaded two times.

I know there is a way to do this with selenium webdriver, but this is not the right way for me because i used the followed code for several emulated devices to test this website and on iOS/Mac osx its working.
So why not on android. My way to test this website is with capybara, appium and ruby.

on iOS there exists a

```
:safariInitialUrl =>'http://www.mypage.com'
```

cap.
but not for android.
So, my question is: how is it possible to start my website on an emulated android devices without using selenium webdriver.

code:

```
Capybara.register_driver :androidphone do |app|

capabilities = {
:deviceName => 'nex5_5', 
:avd => 'nex5_5', 
:browserName => 'Chrome', 
:platformVersion => '5.0', 
:platformName => 'Android', 
:automationName => 'Appium',
}

url = "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"

appium_lib_options = {
server_url: url
}

all_options = {
appium_lib: appium_lib_options,
caps: capabilities,
}

Appium::Capybara::Driver.new app, all_options
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line in your config file :
    exports.config = {
        directConnect:false, 
    }

I think you have also to add the Timeout in your configuration file, if you are using jasmine framework for example add this code :

```
 jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
```